# HTML tooltip is not displayed in Jupyter notebook

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

I am following [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) of adding tooltip to HTML. It works in a standalone HTML file, but when I try to embed it into Jupyter, I see no "Hower over me" text.

This is my notebook code:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def _set_css_style(css_file_path):
   """
   Read the custom CSS file and load it into Jupyter.
   Pass the file path to the CSS file.
   """
   styles = open(css_file_path, "r").read()
   st = '<style>%s</style>' % styles     
   return HTML(st)

_set_css_style('styles.css')

HTML("""<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

<p>Blah blah blah</p>

</body>
""")
```

And here is the css file:

```
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;

  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Jupyter displays:

```
Move the mouse over the text below:

Blah blah blah
```

​

Comment: inspect the page generated and insure the tag and styles are formatted correctly

Answer (score 2):

Changing `class="tooltip"` to `class="ttooltip"` (as well as resepective CSS class names) fixed it. I am guessing Jupyter has a `tooltip` class already, which conflicted with a newly created class.